# Trying to count similar users from sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, count, group-concat

I have a table like this:

```
user_id | subscription_id
-------------------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 3
2       | 4
3       | 1
3       | 2
4       | 3
5       | 3
```

What I want to do is count how many users have similar subscriptions:

```
user_id | same_subscriptions
----------------------------
1       | 1
2       | 0
3       | 1
4       | 1
5       | 1
```

Is this even possible? How can I achieve this...

Best I managed to do is get a table like this with group_concat:

```
user_id | subscriptions
-----------------------
1       | 1,2
2       | 3,4
3       | 1,2
4       | 3
5       | 3
```

This is how I achieved it:

```
SELECT A.user_id, group_concat(B.subscription_id) 
  FROM Subscriptions A LEFT JOIN Subscriptions B ON 
  A.user_id=B.user_id GROUP BY A.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregate function `GROUP_CONCAT()` does not help in this case because in SQLite it does not support an `ORDER BY` clause, so that a safe comparison can be done.
But you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` window function instead:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY subs) - 1 same_subscriptions
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(subscription_id) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY subscription_id) subs,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY subscription_id DESC) rn
  FROM Subscriptions
)
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY user_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fc99ad907189fc93ec2c9fde2077feb0).
Results:

```
> user_id | same_subscriptions
> ------: | -----------------:
>       1 |                  1
>       2 |                  0
>       3 |                  1
>       4 |                  1
>       5 |                  1
```